# absolute beginner: basic question - limiting the time of power output

Tags: power

I am completely new to `Electrical Engineering` (and english is not my mother tounge) so please be gently with me :)

take the following as given:

- power source
- LED
- Switch (manual - nothing electrical!)

when the user presses the switch - `event` shall establish an power output for the LED, but it shall only output power for a given time (x milliseconds)

is it possible to accomplish this without a microcontroller?

Comment: Sounds like you want a one shot timer circuit

Comment: i try to implement a sort of "light gun"; when the trigger is pushed the led shall emit light - so pushing the button switch (no clue which switch shall be used)

Answer (score 1):

The following simple circuit will produce a light pulse

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsDPzU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The capacitor is charged when the switch is in the initial state. When the switch is activated it is discharged through the LED.

Size the capacitor according to the length of the desired pulse.

Comment: Nice, but give the guy some numbers. S/he's unlikely to be able to work them out.

Comment: Pretty good answer and honestly, I was expecting someone to talk about timers. But yes, please indicate use OP's specs and how your solution might be good for what they're trying to do.

Comment: Your circuit is missing a very important part...the part that limits the current that charges the capacitor.

Comment: which numbers do i need if i want the led to light for 10 or 20ms?